# Stack Info: a Chrome extension to display information from Stack Overflow and help you follow your reputation

Tags: app, reputation, chrome-extensions

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Extension in action]

[image: Notification of your reputation]

### About

Chrome Extension to display information from Stack Overflow and help you follow your reputation.

It is fairly simple project (especially compared to other chrome extensions posted here) but I wanted a way to know when something happen on my account.

I want to focus on the gamification part, like helping to find the next step, or the next badge.

#### License

This extension is published under the MIT license.

#### Download

Install *Stack Info* from [the Google Web Store (mckpbfbhkaoemgfcjbloopjgclmkeoll)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-info/mckpbfbhkaoemgfcjbloopjgclmkeoll).

#### Platform

Only Chrome for now. I don't plan to port it to Firefox, but it probably wouldn't be too hard.

### Contact

Feel free to [report any issues to me on Github](https://github.com/athieriot/stack-info/issues).
You can learn more about me on my profile.

### Code

This extension is pretty small and I jumped on the occasion to experiment with some libraries:

- [The React framework](http://facebook.github.io/react/)
- [Oboe Rest client](http://oboejs.com/)

The code is on GitHub and you code read it or fork here: [github.com/athieriot/stack-info](https://github.com/athieriot/stack-info)